# TSQL - update based on value between two ints in 2nd table.

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

Having an issue with doing a mass update with millions of rows.  Example of what I'm attempting to do below.  Trying to avoid case statements if possible as there are over 1000 ranks.

Table 1:

```
id, score, rank
1   4090   null
2   6400   null
3   8905   null
4   2551   null
```

Table 2:

```
Rank,  Score
 1      0
 2      1000
 3      3500
 4      5000
 5      8000
 6      10000
```

I'm attempting to update table 1 to display the correct rank.
EX: ID 2 having a score of 6400 would be above 5000 but below 8000 therefore be rank 4.  Is this possible without a case statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
update t1
    set rank = t2.rank
    from table1 t1 cross apply
         (select top 1 t2.*
          from table2 t2
          where t2.score <= t1.score
          order by t2.score desc
         ) t2;
```

For millions of rows I would suggest one of the following:

- Do the update in batches.
- Use a `case` statement.
- Put the output in a new table, truncate the original table, and reload

"Millions" of updates is often a very expensive operation.

Comment: This seems to work for me.  I'll do more spot checking tomorrow.  We bring our environment down during these kinds of patches.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another Option is with a simple JOIN in concert with Lead()

**Example**

```
Update Table1 Set Rank=B.Rank
 From  Table1 A
 Join  (
            Select Rank
                  ,R1=Score
                  ,R2=Lead(Score,1,999999) over (Order By Score)
             From Table2
       ) B on A.score >= B.R1 and A.Score < B.R2
```

**Returns**

```
id  score   rank
1   4090    3
2   6400    4
3   8905    5
4   2551    2
```